# Laravel meta description

Tags: php, laravel

I have page product. And I have code `meta description`:

```
@section('meta-desc', mb_substr(strip_tags($product['content']), 0, 157) . '...')
```

In variable `$product['content']` can be html tags. I have filter.

But I get codes `nbsp;..` and spaces..

How I can do correctly filter for meta description?

Thanks

Comment: Try PHP function `html_entity_decode` on the `$product['content']` before stripping the tags.

Comment: You need to pass the content string to `html_entity_decode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to:

```
@section('meta-desc')
     {!! mb_substr($product['content'], 0, 157) !!}...
@endsection
```

Also, instead of:

```
mb_substr(strip_tags($product['content']), 0, 157)
```

You can use [`str_limit()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-str-limit):

```
str_limit(strip_tags($product['content']), 157)
```

Comment: I get `&nbsp;` :( Google don't want index this.

Comment: @Jajaja use `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}`

Comment: `<meta name="description" content="    Шикарная джинсовая куртка - модная новинка 2018 года!&nbsp;
Размер&nbsp;90см(8) / 95см(10)&nbsp;
❄ Утеплена махровой толстой подкладкой. Верх из плотной не ...
">` Not working :(

Comment: @Jajaja I've just tested your string in 5.5 and it doesn't display `&nbsp;`. I did this `{!! 'Шикарная джинсовая куртка - модная новинка 2018 года!&nbsp; Размер&nbsp;90см(8) / 95см(10)&nbsp; ❄ Утеплена махровой толстой подкладкой. Верх из плотной не ...' !!}`

Comment: I have: `@section('meta-desc')
    {!! mb_substr(strip_tags($product['content']), 0, 157) !!} ...
@endsection` And get nbsp

Comment: Sorry. All working. I get `<meta name="description" content="    
 Милые 3D усы, кот
 
 
 Мягкий силиконовый материал, износостойкие и ударопрочные
 
 ...
">` But with spaces. How I can remove spaces?

Comment: @Jajaja if you're talking about spaces in the beginning and at the end of the string, use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Comment: @Jajaja well, place the code in the same line then, like `@section('meta-desc') {!! mb_substr..... !!} @endsection`

Comment: And if I not use `strip_tags` I get html tags in meta.

Comment: @Jajaja not working what? You'll still have space, but it will be smaller. If you want to get rid of spaces, you'll need to rewrite section like this `<meta name="description" @section(...) content="{!! .... !!}" @endsection >`.

Comment: And if I not use strip_tags I get html tags in meta.

Comment: @Jajaja well, use it then. Your original problem is solved with `{!! !!}`